# [Swift][Xcode11]Build succeeds, but iOS simulator does not start

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

Build succeeds, but iOS simulator does not start.

When I opened "Edit Schemes", the "Executable" setting of "Run" was "None".

I think this is the cause, but there is no "project name.app" in the options.

[image: Edit Schemes]

The following error was displayed in the simulator system log:

> Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim, error = 2: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreLocationProtobuf.framework/CoreLocationProtobuf, error = 2: No such file or directory
>
> assertion failed: 19E242d 17E5233e: com.apple.alarm + 4116 [3A8B133A-F812-3AF3-A390-C970E8DBF8C9]: 0x0

Comment: Can you show me all project schemes?

Comment: Try system reboot. Sometimes trouble is it.

Comment: Thank you. There is only one project scheme, "project name-Package".

Comment: Thank you. It did not change even after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using some different scheme. Go to New Scheme and add a new one. And run your project through that.

Comment: Thank you. There was only one scheme. I added a new scheme in the following steps, but the simulator did not start. 1. Click Manage Schemes. 2. Click the Add button. 3. Select [Project Name] and click the [OK] button.

Comment: Are you getting any error message like "Not able to start", etc

Comment: Did not appear.
However, after rebuilding, "Projects Tests.xctest" under "Products" turned red. After checking the path, it looks like "Project name Tests.xctest" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your simulator in which you are trying to run. Launch the simulator, follow the below steps

> Hardware -> Erase all contents and settings -> Run the app.

If it doesn't work please attach the error that you seeing on Xcode when you are trying to launch the simulator.

Comment: Thank you.
Since the simulator does not start, it cannot be reset.
Also, no error is displayed.
However, after rebuilding, "Projects Tests.xctest" under "Products" turned red. After checking the path, it looks like "Project name Tests.xctest" does not exist.

Comment: You can launch the simulator from the following path

Xcode->Open Developer Tool->Simulator. Also, try removing the missing files in Red from the project and rebuild

Comment: The following error was displayed in the simulator system log: Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim, error = 2: No such file or directory

Comment: Files shown in red cannot be deleted because deletion is disabled.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm also having trouble with the "Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim"

Comment: @scaly did you find any solution? Please